# Receiving "The name 'ModelName' does not exist in the current context' when the model is imported ASP.NET MVC 4'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone explain to me why i get the following error:
The name 'Messanger' does not exist in the current context from IIS server when i have imported the class and even Visual Studio doesn't detect an error?

xxxxx.Models.Messanger:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace XXXX.Models
{
    public class Messanger
    {
        private Messanger()
        {
        }
        public static Messanger Instance
        {
            get
            {
                var output = HttpContext.Current.Session["MessangerInstance"] as Messanger;
                if (output == null)
                {
                    output = new Messanger();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["MessangerInstance"] = output;
                }
                return output;
            }
        }
        private List<string> Success = new List<string>();
        private List<string> Info = new List<string>();
        private List<string> Warning = new List<string>();
        public void addSuccess(string message)
        {
            Success.Add(message);
        }
        public void addSuccess(List<string> messages)
        {
            Success.AddRange(messages);
        }
        public void addInfo(string message)
        {
            Info.Add(message);
        }
        public void addInfo(List<string> messages)
        {
            Info.AddRange(messages);
        }
        public void addWarning(string message)
        {
            Warning.Add(message);
        }
        public void addWarning(List<string> messages)
        {
            Warning.AddRange(messages);
        }
        public List<string> getSuccess()
        {
            return Success;
        }
        public List<string> getInfo()
        {
            return Info;
        }
        public List<string> getWarning()
        {
            return Warning;
        }
        public void addMessage(IMessageType message)
        {
            if (message.getType() == "success")
            {
                Success.Add(message.getMessage());
            }
            else if (message.getType() == "warning")
            {
                Warning.Add(message.getMessage());
            }
            else Info.Add(message.getMessage());
        }
        public void addMessage(List<IMessageType> messages)
        {
            foreach (IMessageType message in messages)
            {
                addMessage(message);
            }
        }
        public int getMessageCount()
        {
            return Success.Count + Info.Count + Warning.Count;
        }
        public bool ThereAreMessages()
        {
            return (getMessageCount() > 0);
        }
    }
    public interface IMessageType
    {
        string getType();
        string getMessage();
    }
    public abstract class Message : IMessageType
    {
        private string MessageStore;
        private string Type;
        public Message(string message, string type)
        {
            this.MessageStore = message;
            this.Type = type;
        }
        string IMessageType.getType()
        {
            return Type;
        }
        string IMessageType.getMessage()
        {
            return this.MessageStore;
        }

    }
    public class SuccessMessage : Message
    {
        public SuccessMessage(string message)
            : base(message, "success")
        {

        }

    }
    public class InfoMessage : Message
    {
        public InfoMessage(string message)
            : base(message, "info")
        {

        }
    }
    public class WarningMessage : Message
    {
        public WarningMessage(string message)
            : base(message, "warning")
        {

        }
    }

}
```

and my _Layout.cshtml Razor view is:

```
@using XXXXX.Models
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XXXXX - @ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="@Url.Content("/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css")" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form form-inline pull-right" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Login", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl})">
              @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
              <input type="text" name="UserName" autofocus placeholder="Username">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password">
              <input type="hidden" value="true" name="RememberMe">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
          </form>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="container">
          @if (Messanger.Instance.ThereAreMessages())
          {
              if(Messanger.Instance.getWarning().Count > 0)
              {
                  <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">  
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        @foreach (string message in Messanger.Instance.getWarning())
                        {
                            @message;<br>
                        }
                        </div>               
                  </div>
              }
              if (Messanger.Instance.getSuccess().Count > 0)
              {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    @foreach (string message in Messanger.Instance.getSuccess())
                    {
                        @message;
                    }
                    </div>
                </div>
              }
              if (Messanger.Instance.getInfo().Count > 0)
              {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    @foreach (string message in Messanger.Instance.getInfo())
                    {
                        @message;
                    }
                    </div> 
                </div>
              }
          }
          @RenderBody()
      </div>
    <!-- End of content-->
    <script src="@Url.Content("/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/js/bootstrap.js")"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the error when trying to access XXXXX.Models.Messanger.ThereAreMessages() at line 49.

EDIT: i managed to fix the first error by making the model class static. After that i got a strange error but I realised that I added System.Models in the webconfig in the views file which caused the error.

Now I have another problem. I use the Messanger for getting messages throughout the site. I have a login form and if the submited data isn't valid, I push the errors to the Messanger and then display them. The problem is that when the data is invalid the errors are displayed as expected but after each refresh the same messages keep stacking again and again. ASP.NET is stateless and after each refresh the classes should be instanciated again, im not storing the messages into a database but still they keep stacking. Can someone help me fix it?

Comment: Do you have any `<namespaces>` setup in the `~/Views/web.config`? Also, is `@XXXX.Models` an implied `@using XXXX.Models` or `@model XXXX.Models`?

Comment: so that answers the `@using`; But now where is `Messanger` coming from (looks like VS and I have the same question)? You're in `_Layout` so there's no `Model`; Is is a static class?

Comment: I have edited the view. It is @using xxx.Models. I haven't touched the config file. I'm new to ASP.NET and don't really know how everything is handled yet.

Comment: try using `public static class Messanger` instead of just `public class Messanger`. (it looks like it's meant to be a static class anyways, so make sure VS knows it--though it really shouldn't matter).

Comment: Im trying to import the class xxxx.Models.Messanger which has only static properties and methods into the view with the @@using statement. Can i use the @@model statement in the main layout when no controller has passed a model instance to it?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. As long as VS knows what it is (which is should given your `@using` statement) you should be able to call static methods off of the class.

Comment: after i changed the model to be static, now i get new error: The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) and in yellow is marked : "Line 22:     using System.Web.WebPages;
Line 23:     using System.Web.Mvc;
Line 24:     using System.Web.Models;
Line 25:     using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
Line 26:     using System.Web.Mvc.Html;" and line 24 is in red

Comment: I managed to fix it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, feel free to post the process you took as an answer then, after time has elapsed, accept it. This not only helps your own reputation, but guides anyone else who found this question (e.g. google/search) to the right solution.

Comment: Can you please check the edited version?

Comment: Looks good, but should be an actual answer not a revision of the question. ;-)

Comment: `ASP.NET is stateless` is very wrong.  ASP.Net is VERY stateful. Websites run in a Application Pool that has a Current AppDomain with many cached objects to keep a website running quickly.  Don't confuse `I want to write a stateless website` with what ASP.Net does in the background.  The only time state is lost is when the application pool starts (from a restart, crash or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your last update. Your `Messanger` class is static. Asp.Net is not stateless, but the http requests it processes are stateless. When a class is static, exactly one instance of that class exists per application domain. When deployed to a web server, IIS will create at least one app domain per web application (called an app pool) and that can serve many requests. However if IIS determines the request load is too high, it may choose to spin up a new app domain to handle them. What you will experience is every user of the system will see the exact same instance of messages even if they did not create that message.

Static classes and members in the web environment can be very dangerous if not handled properly.

One possible fix for your problem would be to wrap the instance up in session. *Remove all static modifiers* from your `Messanger` and add the following property:

```
public static Messanger Instance
{
    get
    {
        var output = HttpContext.Current.Session["MessangerInstance"] as Messanger;
        if (output == null)
        {
            output = new Messanger();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["MessangerInstance"] = output;
        }
        return output;        
    }
}
```

You may also choose to make the constructor for `Messanger` private.

Now, when you access `Messanger` do it like so:

```
Messanger.Instance
```

It will always be one per user, per session.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I made an edit of my model and view and it keeps stacking the messages. Any ideas why it's happening? I come from a PHP background (have written more than 15K lines, which I think is good enough for my age and experience) and it was much simpler to reason about anything.

Comment: The messages stack because a single instance of `Messanger` is created for each user session. This session instance will span all requests from that user until they "log out" or their session expires.

Comment: If you want the scope of `Messanger` to be per request just change `HttpContext.Current.Session...` to `HttpContext.Current.Items...`

Comment: If you want the scope of `Messenger` to be per application just change it to `HttpContext.Application.Items`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Now I have to understand how it works. I will try to implement RoR/CodeIgniter flashmessages, too.